# Mantener estilos en distintos enlaces de la página web

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo una página web para practicar; la cosa es que tengo todos los estilos de la página desarrollada. En el menú de navegación del index tengo enlazado las páginas correspondientes a los elementos del menú. Al clikear el hipervínculo, teniendo el mismo archivo css llamado en las distintas páginas, estas se cargan sin estilos. Me fijo en el código de la pagina y si está siendo llamado, pero no están siendo utilizados
¿Se necesita un framework, algún lenguaje especifico, para que en los estilos de la pagina principal se mantengan en las subpáginas? o ¿cómo se hace?.
Gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Hola, por favor muestra el codigo que tienes y donde está el problema para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Pon el código  de cada página donde llamas al archivo CSS, poruqe supongo que en cada página haces la llamada al archivo de estilos.

Comment: ahora agrego imagenes, nose si uno de mis errores es que al copiar y pegar el codigo entero estan siendo llamados los mismos id(se que es algo unico) en las distintas paginas, sera eso lo que hace que se me trabe la pagina?

Answer (score 1):

para que los estilos se sobrepongan a los que no quieres mostrar bebes tener en orden los archivos al agregarlos es decir, si tienes varios archivos y quieres que se tome primero seria algo asi:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estiloSecundario.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estiloPrimario.css" />
```

ya que el codigo siempre se lee de arriba para abajo

en caso de que sea un unico archivo debes tener en cuenta el orden de las definiciones en el archivo.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa la ruta del archivo css

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../ccs/archivodeestilo.css" type="text/css">`

Comment: me falto un punto al establecer la ruta lo tenia ./"x" en vez de ../"" para indicarle que el archivo esta en otra carpeta

Comment: exacto!! si el archivo esta en el mismo directorio se coloca css/archivo.css; pero si esta en otro directorio debes ir colocando ../css/archivo.css.

Comment: ¿Revisar qué cosa, qué parte de la ruta?